Debugging VBA macro - macro to change hard formatting (underline and strikethrough) into tracked changes in one click
Currently I have the following macro to change hard formatting in Word into tracked/marked-up formatting:
Sub HardToTracked()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrTxt As String
With ActiveDocument
With .Range
With .Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .text = ""
  .Replacement.text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Format = True
  .Font.StrikeThrough = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Execute
End With
Do While .Find.Found
  .End = .Words.Last.End
  StrTxt = .text
  ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
  .text = StrTxt
  ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
  .Delete
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Find.Execute
Loop
End With
With .Range
With .Find
  .ClearFormatting
  .Replacement.ClearFormatting
  .text = ""
  .Replacement.text = ""
  .Forward = True
  .Format = True
  .Font.Underline = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  .Execute
  End With
  Do While .Find.Found
  If .Words.First.Previous = "  " Then
    .Start = .Start - 1
  Else
    .End = .Words.Last.End
  End If
  StrTxt = .text
  ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = False
  .text = vbNullString
  ActiveDocument.TrackRevisions = True
  .text = StrTxt
  .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
  .Find.Execute
  Loop
End With
.TrackRevisions = False
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

This currently bleeds the tracked-version of "strikethrough" (i.e., deletion formatting) into the tracked-version of "underline" when those strings are next to each other.  In other words, this happens:

Where's the bug in this code which is causing insertions to be shown as simultaneous deletions?
Seems like it's an easy fix but I'm missing something obvious...
